# problemas impresión html en php

Tags: php, html, curl

tengo una función en php que me devuelve un array y necesito maquetar una página para poder insertar los datos del array, el problema es que no veo el error porque me imprime todo el html en vez de renderizarla. Me podéis ayudar? OS dejo el código.

Por consola no me da ningún tipo de error... Gracias por adelantado

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
function clienteId(){
        $error = '';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:password');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://web.api.com/api/clienteid/358');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_errno($ch);
        if($error){
            echo ("Error: ".$error);
            die;
        }else{
            curl_close($ch);
        }
        $result = (array) json_decode($json);

        return $result;
    }

    $var = clienteId();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Panel Cliente Citra</title>
    <meta name='Panel Cliente' content='Panel de Cliente'> 
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./vendor/components/font-awesome/css/all.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./assets/css/styles.css'>
    <script src='./vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/src/popover.js'></script>
    <script src='./vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/src/dropdown.js'></script>
    <script src='./vendor/nnnick/chartjs/src/index.js'></script>
    <script src='./vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='./vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='./assets/js/main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No me he dado cuenta, tan solo dejar comentada la siguiente línea, y ya funciona bien:

```
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Es decir, así:

```
// header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Si tienes idea de por que eso funcionó, podrías explicar por que hacer eso solucionó tu problema? Vendría genial para las personas que vean tu respuesta en el futuro!